# Restricting access to a certain Page Type based on group member is in?

Tags: silverstripe

I am working on a project for a Gym. I have a page type called `GymLocationPage`.

Every gym will have their own `GymLocationPage` added by an admin - Every gym will have a login for each of their gym managers. In the Security area I have created a group called `Gym Manager` and have added them to this group when member gets created.

When the gym manager logs in, I only want them to be able to view and edit **their** gym's `GymLocationPage` and no other pages/model admins etc.

How do I go about doing this with a particular page type and also making sure the current logged in user gets to only edit their particular gym's page.

E.g

**Bob** is New Yorks gym manager => He can only access New York's gym location page (Can't see any other gym locations or other pages etc).

---

**John** is Californias gym manager => He can only access Californias gym location page (Can't see any other gym locations or other pages etc).

Answer (score 3):

SilverStripe has a pretty nice [permission management](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/security/permissions/). You can create permissions in your code and add manually to a user group.

```
<?php
class Foo extends DataObject implements PermissionProvider
{

    /**
     * Return a map of permission codes to add to the dropdown 
     * shown in the Security section of the CMS.
     * array(
     *   'VIEW_SITE' => 'View the site',
     * );
     */
    public function providePermissions()
    {
        return [
            'FOO_MANAGE' => [
                'name' => _t('FOO.PERMISSION_MANAGE_DESCRIPTION', 'Create, edit and delete Foo Items'),
                'category' => _t('Permissions.FOO_CATEGORY', 'Foo'),
            ],
            'FOO_CREATE' => [
                'name' => _t('FOO.PERMISSION_CREATE_DESCRIPTION', 'Create Foo Items'),
                'category' => _t('Permissions.FOO_CATEGORY', 'Foo'),
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

In the DataObject or your Page type you can then check the different `can` methods to define what user can view, can edit, can delete etc... that.

`canView()` is for "accessing" the page in frontend, `canEdit()` for editing it in backend.

```
/**
 * @param null $member
 * @return bool
 */
public function canView($member = null)
{
    //this method is for accessing / viewing the page.
    return true;
}

/**
 * @param null $member
 * @return bool
 */
public function canCreate($member = null)
{
    $parent = parent::canCreate($member);

    $manage = Permission::check('FOO_MANAGE', 'any', $member);
    $create = Permission::check('FOO_CREATE', 'any', $member);

    return $parent || $manage || $create;
}

/**
 * @param null $member
 * @return bool
 */
public function canEdit($member = null)
{
    $member = $member ?: Member::currentUser();
    $parent = parent::canCreate($member);

    $manage = Permission::check('FOO_MANAGE', 'any', $member);

    //you can check everyting here...
    $owner = $member ? $this->OwnerID == $member->ID : false;

    return $parent || $manage || $owner;
}

/**
 * @param null $member
 * @return bool
 */
public function canDelete($member = null)
{
    $parent = parent::canCreate($member);

    $manage = Permission::check('FOO_MANAGE', 'any', $member);

    return $parent || $manage;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What I am trying to get my head around at the moment is how to assign a member to their specific `GymLocationPage` only. E.g Bob is the gym manager of the New York gym. If I give all my members in the `Gym Manger` group the same permission then won't they all be able to see each others gym location pages instead of just seeing their own?

Answer (score 2):

> If I give all my members in the Gym Manger group the same permission then won't they all be able to see each others gym location pages instead of just seeing their own?

Not if you properly implement your `canXXX()` methods on each `GymLocationPage` as @wmk has done for you above. It needs to include checks on the relevant `Group` but the part you're probably missing is how to relate each page to each individual `Member` record. You can achieve this by extending `Member` with a `$has_one` relation to `GymLocationPage` thus:

```
class GymMemberExtension extends DataExtension
{
    private static $has_one = array(
        'GymPage' => 'GymLocationPage'
    );
}
```

..and ensure the user's correct `GymLocationPage` via the `Member.GymPageID` field is populated when the user is created.

There is also the 2nd param to `Permission::check()` to consider which TBH I've never spotted before. It seems to allow for very specific types of entries in the `Permission` table, but haven't seen any examples as to how this is used in the wild.